# Can explain what is necesariy the extra rule on this PEG

Tags: javascript, peg

I'm playing with [PEG.js](http://pegjs.majda.cz/) and reading and in the [Nathans University](http://nathansuniversity.com/pegs6.html) i found a good "explain" how to build my own languaje but i'm stuck with this step

i dont understand the `primary` can explain me please

```
start =
    comma

comma = 
    left: additive "," right:comma 
        { return {tag: ",", left:left, right:right}; }
    / additive

additive =
    left:multiplicative "+" right:additive
        { return {tag: "+", left:left, right:right}; }
  / multiplicative

multiplicative =
    left:primary "*" right:multiplicative
        { return {tag: "*", left:left, right:right}; }
  / primary

primary =
    integer
  / "(" comma:comma  ")" # Can explain me why is necesary "(" and ")"
      { return comma; }

integer =
    digits:[0-9]+
        { return parseInt(digits.join(""), 10); }
```

### test

```
var parse = wrapExceptions(PEG.buildParser(answer).parse);

assert_eq(parse("1+2"),
    {tag:"+", left:1, right:2},
    "parse 1+2");
assert_eq(parse("1+2*3"),
    {tag:"+", left:1, right:{tag:"*", left:2, right:3}},
    "parse 1+2*3");
assert_eq(parse("1,2"),
    {tag:",", left:1, right:2},
    "parse 1,2");
assert_eq(parse("1,2+3"),
    {tag:",", left:1, right:{tag:"+", left:2, right:3}},
    "parse 1,2+3");
assert_eq(parse("1*2,3"),
    {tag:",", left:{tag:"*", left:1, right:2}, right:3},
    "parse 1*2,3");
```

my question is why is necesary the `/ "(" comma:comma  ")"` if the entry does not have parenthesis, if remove that line the last test fails

Comment: This may be obvious, but `primary` is either an `integer` or a `comma` surrounded by `()`s. What is exactly your doubt?

Answer (score 0):

The line in question is the *first part* of an alternative expression, for the `primary` rule -- it is tested only if `integer` does not match.

This alternate expression starts after the `/` and includes the corresponding action block: `{ return comma; }`

Note that "comma" is being used in two distinct ways here -- both as a rule name and also as a label identifier.  See [PEG.js - Parsing Expression Types](http://pegjs.majda.cz/documentation#grammar-syntax-and-semantics-parsing-expression-types):

> ***label*** : *expression*
>
> Match the expression and remember its match result under given label. The label must be a JavaScript identifier. ...

So, `integer / "(" comma:comma ")"` first attempts to match `integer`; if that fails it then attempts to match the entire second expression.

The label could be any valid JavaScript identifier.  Please consider the following snippet, which is functionally-equivalent to your example:

```
primary =
    integer
  / "(" result:comma ")"
      { return result; }
```

If parenthesis are not relevant then you could omit the *entire second expression*, leaving just:

```
primary =
    integer
```

As another quick example of labeling, this would also work (but is redundant):

```
primary =
    anumber:integer
      { return anumber; }
```

Comment: if you remove the ` / "(" comma:comma  ")"`  line the sample dont work

Comment: correct; think of the two lines after the ```/``` like ```function(comma) { return comma; }```.  you are only removing the ```function(comma)``` part -- and apparently leaving behind the trailing, related ```{ return comma; }``` part?  if you remove the line in question, you must also remove the related action...